# Implement custom cell in TTTableView to a TTViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

I have TTViewController include a TTTableView inside and init TTTableView like below:

```
- (void)loadView{
    appTableView = [[TTTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, self.view.width - 20, (self.view.height - 44 - 49)/2 - 40)];
        appTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        appTableView.delegate = self;
        appTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        [self.view addSubview:appTableView];
}
```

and in

```
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
   appTableView.dataSource = [TTListDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:
                           [CustomTTTableSubtitleItem itemWithTitle:result.resourceName text:textCombine ],nil];

}
```

I've coded this:

```
- (Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id) object { 

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[CustomTTTableSubtitleItem class]]) { 
        NSLog(@"here");
        return [CustomTTTableSubtitleItemCell class];       
    } 
    else { 
        return [self tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object]; 
    }
}
```

and of course I added protocol

```
@interface TestController : TTViewController<TTTableViewDelegate,TTTableViewDataSource>
```

but seems -(Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id) object  not be called... anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `- (Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id) object` is a TTTableViewDataSource function, so you will have to extend the TTListDataSource into your own data source class, and override this function there and not under TTViewController.

In your TTViewController, create the custom data source:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(TTURLRequest*)request {
    self.dataSource = [[[YourDataDataSource alloc] 
                      initWithResults:results] autorelease];
}
```

and in your custom TTTableViewDataSource have your  `- (Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id) object`  custom function

Comment: Great!!!! @aporat, it works!!!! Many thanks!!!! But there is a new problem, + (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)item in custom cell not called, however other datasource class who call CustomTTTableSubtitleItem can rowHeightForObject this work... I wrote [self.items addObject:[CustomTTTableSubtitleItem.... in init method, is that the matter?

Comment: do u need a variable row height between cell items? you can set the row height for all the cells using     self.tableView.rowHeight = 70.0f;